# reverse-alphabetizing a string in c

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
int i, temp;
char input[50];

printf("Enter a string: \n");
scanf("%s", input);

for(i=0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(strcmp(input[i], input[i+1])<0) {
        temp=input[i];
        input[i]=input[i+1];
        input[i+1]=temp;
        }
    }
printf("%s\n", input);
return(0);
}
```

I am supposed to write a program which sorts the characters of a user-inputted string into backwards alphabetical order.  I believe I am using the strcmp function incorrectly?

Comment: unless you invented bubble sort algorithm with `O(n)` complexity, you need 2 loops to do that kind of sort.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing chars, you dont need to use `strcmp` which compares null terminated char arrays.

a simple `input[i] == input[i+1]` will be OK.

this will compare the ascii codes of the characters.

Comment: copy/paste comment: unless you invented bubble sort algorithm with `O(n)` complexity, you need 2 loops to do that kind of sort. Enter `acbac`, the loop will not be enough to move the last `c` in 2nd position.

Comment: other than that, he is using strcmp with no reason

Comment: right, but with your input, OP is still not able to perform a sort properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use qsort?

```
int compareFunction(const void *a, const void *b) {
    char char1 = 0[(char *) a];
    char char2 = 0[(char *) b];
    if (char1 > char2) return -1;
    if (char1 == char2) return 0;
    if (char1 < char2) return 1;
}

....

qsort(input, strlen(input), 1, compareFunction);
```

Comment: Do you really write `0[(char *) a]`? Much more readable would be `*(char *) a`.

Comment: Yeah, my coding style is weird.

Comment: `qsort(input, 1, 1, compareFunction);` has no effect.

Comment: _backwards alphabetical order_

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp` is used to compare char *arrays* not chars themselves, which can be simply compared with `>`.

That's not the only problem: bubble sort needs 2 loops (`O(n**2)` complexity) so even with the compare fix, your loop doesn't sort it completely. For instance, enter `acbac`, one loop will not be enough to move the last `c` in 2nd position since it only swaps neighbour elements once.

Here's an implementation which does the job, using a double loop (with half of the string in the inner loop) and proper `char` comparison.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
int i,j, temp;
char input[50];

printf("Enter a string: \n");
scanf("%49s", input);

for(i=0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
   for(j=i+1; input[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    if (input[i] < input[j]) {
        temp=input[i];
        input[i]=input[j];
        input[j]=temp;
        }
    }
}
printf("%s\n", input);
return(0);
}
```